# copy dynamic range from one tab to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have sheet A and sheet B. Sheet A has cells J1 and I1 whose cell value changes based on other functions. These values are used to copy range from Sheet B and copy Sheet to row number (updated in cell J1).  but i am getting error as "Cannot convert Range to (class)." while executing.

`````
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("A");
  var lastRow=  sheet.getRange("J1");
  var lastrowV = sheet.getRange("I1");  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("B");
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastrowV,11);
  var data = range.getValues();
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("A");
    sheet.getRange(LAstRow,1, data.length, 11).setValues(data);
   }````
`````

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what happens in the code.

You can't set `lastrowV` as a number because it's a range

```
var lastrowV = sheet.getRange("I1");
```

You can't use `LAstRow` besause it's not exist. If you try set `lastRow` you'll catch the issue like with `lastrowV`

```
sheet.getRange(LAstRow,1, data.length, 11).setValues(data)
```

Don't swipe a variable like `sheet`

```
sheet = ...
var sheet = ...
var sheet = ...
```